# questions about sink, in R

Tags: r, file-io

Lets say I want to use sink for writing to a file in R.

```
sink("outfile.txt")
cat("Line one.\n")
cat("Line two.")
sink()
```

question 1. I have seen people writing sink() at the end, why do we need this? Can something go wrong when we do not have this?

question 2. What is the best way to write many lines one by one to file with a for-loop, where you also need to format each line? That is I might need to have different number in each line, like in python I would use outfile.write("Line with number %.3f",1.231) etc.

Comment: I prefer being explicit and use `cat(..., file = ., append = TRUE)` to write to a file and thus avoid `sink` altogether. Also see `writeLines`.

Comment: For your first question - check the third paragraph in the Details section of `?sink`

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:**
The `sink` function redirects all text going to the `stdout` stream to the file handler you give to `sink`. This means that *anything* that would normally print out into your interactive R session, will now instead be written to the file in sink, in this case "outfile.txt".
When you call `sink` again without any arguments you are telling it to resume using `stdout` instead of "outfile.txt". So no, nothing will go wrong if you don't call `sink()` at the end, but you need to use it if you want to start seeing output again in your R session/

As @Roman has pointed out though, it is better to explicitly tell `cat` to output to the file. That way you get only what you want, and expect to see in the file, while still getting the rest ouf the output in the R session.

**Question 2:**
This also answers question two. R (as far as I am aware) does not have direct file handling like in `python`. Instead you can just use `cat(..., file="outfile.txt")` inside a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, but when I for instance write:                         cat("Line %d.\n",1, file="outy.txt")
cat("Line %d.",2,file="outy.txt",append=T)                                     It doesn't seem to get the format, there isn't some kind of printf function I can use?

Comment: @user2592222 `cat("Line 1.\n", file = "outy.txt")`, `cat("Line 2.\n", file = "outy.txt)`, etc. if you are printing a variable `cat("Line ", x, ".\n", sep = "", file = "outy.txt")`. also see `?sprintf` and `?formatC` for more formatting

Comment: String printing doesn't work the same way in R as in C. The function you're looking for is `sprintf` but this isn't needed, as cat will handle type concatenation on its own.
`cat(sprintf("Line %d.\n", 1), file="outy.txt")` is equivalent to `cat("Line", 1, ".\n", file="outy.txt")`. You can also specify the separator between arguments to cat using the argument `sep`.